# how to maintain session using Shared Preferences

Tags: android, session

I am developing an app,in that i am maintaining Session using Shared Preferences.I that when user login,i am using their email id for further use.But when i tried to use that email in another activity, it is showing null.
Below in my code for mainActivity:

```
    public class main extends AppCompatActivity {
public Button submit;


public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
public static final String email = "emailkey";
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    ImageView i1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgLogo);

    String checkBoxText = "I agree to all the";
    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    checkBox.setText(Html.fromHtml(checkBoxText));
    checkBox.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_email);
            EditText p1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password);
            String e = e1.getText().toString();
            final String password = p1.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

            editor.putString(email, e);

            editor.commit();
```

Here is my code for another activity:

```
           String e,email;

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.internshipsdetails);
      SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(main.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    sharedpreferences.getString(email,e);
    String url = "url?COMP_REQ_ID=" + title + "&StuEmail=" + e;
    AQuery mAQuery = new AQuery(InternShipsDetails.this);
    mAQuery.ajax(url, String.class, new AjaxCallback<String>() {

        @Override

        public void callback(String url, String data, AjaxStatus status) {

            super.callback(url, data, status);
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.d("###$Request URL", url + "");
                Log.d("###$Response ", data + "");
                Log.d("###$Status Message : ", status.getMessage() + "");
                Log.d("###$Status Code : ", status.getCode() + "");

            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the wrong key to shared Pref because of that you are getting null.

Following is the updated code of yours which will give you the stored email address:

```
      SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(main.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  e = sharedpreferences.getString(main.email,"");
    String url = "url?COMP_REQ_ID=" + title + "&StuEmail=" + e;
```

Happy coding !!!

Answer (score 6):

You can manage session by changing shared preference values after doing logout action and check preference again at the time of login also. You can save current time also in a string at login and logout action. Make sure to use private shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

[getString (String key, String defValue)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method returns a `String`. So, you need to catch the output in a `string` variable.
Also, you are passing a `null`key. You need to pass the same key using which you saved the value.

So, in your case it would be

```
e = sharedpreferences.getString("emailkey","nodata");
```